# Using LinkedIn with Firebase and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

We are building a website using Angular JS on the front end, and Firebase for the backend data. We have OAUTH working with Google, Facebook, and even custom auth working with a custom server with username/password. We do need, however, LinkedIn as well.

Currently, Firebase doesn't support LinkedIn, but LI is a "standard" OAUTH2 provider, so I would think there would be a way to create an AuthProvider for the Firebase Javascript.

Using a custom auth server appears to be out of the question. We can't find a workflow that doesn't result in some secret being sent in cleartext.

How would we implement a "Login with LinkedIn" button, to allow us to authenticate with a Firebase backend?

Comment: One example of a secret being sent in plaintext -- if I use a custom login server to do the LI auth, then the JWT needs to be sent back to the client JavaScript.